# Why do we See Black Holes?

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, observers, event-horizon, redshift

The image of things falling into a Black Hole stays frozen on the event horizon forever. So how is it that we don't see the image of a dying star where a Black Hole formed?

We see the black, with an accretion disk.

Comment: We don't "zoom in" close enough to the horizon (the EHT might change this soon) to be able to see the frozen matter.

Comment: This video from Veritasium should help. It explains how the first images of black holes were obtained, and what the image shows. [A Picture of the Milky Way's Supermassive Black Hole](https://www.veritasium.com/videos/2022/5/12/a-picture-of-the-milky-ways-supermassive-black-hole)

Comment: @Prahar Wrong again. If you drop a flashlight to a black hole, the wavelength of its light that we observe becomes larger than the “observable universe” in seconds. Even if EHT were a serious project, but not a joke that it is, it could not detect any such radiation in principle.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the image of accreted material (classically) never vanishes, it becomes more and more redshifted over time. Also, the time interval between individual photons that you would receive becomes longer and longer. One way to think of this is that from the perspective of the infalling material, it only emits a finite number of photons before it crosses the horizon. For the outside observer, those photons must be stretched over a (classically) infinite amount of time.

So if you observe a stellar remnant black hole long enough after it forms, not only would any light you receive from the collapsing star be redshifted beyond the limits of your instrument, it is very likely that you would not even receive a single photon from it.

Comment: Re, "...over time..." Yes, but see John Rennie's answer for thoughts about the length of that interval of time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I saw that. :) My contribution is to note that it's not even just a problem of instrument sensitivity to long wavelengths -- there also simply aren't any photons.

Answer (score 2):

One does not *see* a black hole the way one sees a star. Not even with x-rays or other radiation.

> [Scientists can't directly observe black holes](https://science.nasa.gov/astrophysics/focus-areas/black-holes) with telescopes that detect x-rays, light, or other forms of electromagnetic radiation. We can, however, infer the presence of black holes and study them by detecting their effect on other matter nearby.

The "event horizon" and other mathematical descriptions of a black hole are just that , mathematical descriptions, fitting the data from which one can infer a black hole.

Comment: Mathematics is implemented (made real) into the Universe.

Answer (score 2):

> The image of things falling into a Black Hole stays frozen on the event horizon forever.

This is true, but the light from those things is red shifted as the things approach the horizon, and for a typical black hole the light redshifts to unobservably long wavelengths with a few microseconds.

So if we look at the black hole we are in principle seeing the surface of the star that formed it, but the light from that star has been red shifted so far that it just looks black.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved for non-physicists by noting that redshifting comes with dimming.